# Aggregating values and totals in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

Here is what I am trying to do, Sample Data in a pandas dataframe say df is:

```
ID  Date    Amount

A   5/11/16      5
B   12/10/16    27
B   13/10/16    45
B   14/10/16    2
A   5/12/16     89
C   28/1/16     34
D   29/8/16     12
D   20/5/16     12
C   2/1/17      90
```

For each ID, I want the difference of dates (number of days) in a list, Amounts in another list, Sum of Amounts in final list.

Output be :

```
A [30] [5,89] [94]

B [01,01] [27,45,2] [74]..
```

I tried to group databy :

df = df.groupby('ID')['Amount'].apply(list)

this gives me data grouped by ID and Amount in a list but Im not able to figure how to get diff in dates.

Comment: What is your question? What did you try? What did not work?

Comment: updated now....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could groupby `ID` and the perform a few aggregations.

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%d/%m/%y') # convert to a date column
df = df.groupby('ID').agg({'Date' : lambda x: x.diff().dropna().dt.days, \
                           'Amount' : [lambda y: y.values.tolist(), 'sum']})
df.columns = ['Diff', 'Amount', 'Total']

df

      Diff       Amount  Total
ID                            
A       30      [5, 89]     94
B   [1, 1]  [27, 45, 2]     74
C      340     [34, 90]    124
D     -101     [12, 12]     24
```